# Ошибка библиотеки при использовании firebird

Tags: php, firebase

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_interbase.dll' (tried: c\php\ext\php_interbase.dll (═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.), c\php\ext\php_php_interbase.dll.dll (═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

чем может быть вызвана данная ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не пробовали указать `extension=interbase` вместо `extension=php_interbase.dll` ?

Comment: @P.Fateev не помогает

Comment: надеюсь, вы перезапускаете сервер после внесения изменений в php.ini )
`═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.` -> `Не найден указанный модуль.`  . у 
 вас `extension_dir` правильно указана в php.ini ?

Comment: @P.Fateev думаю да (добавил в вопрос пару скринов)